# Solve Produces no output

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve an eigen value equation to find eigen values U in a specified range but the solve is not working for me, doesn't produce output. The Reduce function and NSolve have the same issue.

```
ncore = 1.4537; nclad = 1;
NA = Sqrt[ncore^2 - nclad^2];
λ = 780*10^-9;
ρ = {0.17*10^-6, 0.5*10^-6, 1*10^-6, 2*10^-6};
V = {2*Pi*ρ*NA/λ};
Δ = (1/2)*(1 - (nclad/ncore)^2); 
W = Sqrt[V^2 - U^2]; 
k = (2*Pi)/λ;
β = Sqrt[(k*ncore)^2 - (U/ρ)^2];
i = 1;
val = (((((1/2)*(BesselJ[0, U] - BesselJ[2, U]))/(U*
      BesselJ[1,U])) + (((1/2)*(BesselK[0, W[[i]]] - 
      BesselK[2, W[[i]]]))/(W[[i]]*BesselK[1, W[[i]]])))*
      ((((1/2)*(BesselJ[0, U] - BesselJ[2, U]))/(U*BesselJ[1, U])) + 
      ((nclad^2*((1/2)*(BesselK[0, W[[i]]] - BesselK[2, 
      W[[i]]])))/(ncore^2*W[[i]]*BesselK[1, W[[i]]])))) -
      (((β[[i]])/(k*ncore))^2*(V[[i]]/(U*W[[i]]))^4);
```

I then use:

```
rootU = Solve[val == 0 && 0 <= U <= V[[i]], U][[All, 1, 2]];
```

or

```
rootU = NSolve[val == 0 && 0 <= U <= V[[i]], U][[All, 1, 2]];
```

Looking forward to your valuable comments.

Comment: Apparently there is no solution satisfying the equation and inequalities. Also you might not want the braces in the definition of `V`.

Comment: Daniel Lichtblau, Yes I put redundant braces in V definition but how should you know that this equation has no solution?

Comment: @UbaidUllah When `Solve` or `NSolve` return `{}`, that means that they found no solutions (look it up e.g. in the Details section of the [documentation for `NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)).

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, on my machine its stuck produce nothing at all at output while the Solve look like it will run forever.

Comment: Plot[val,{U,0,20}] produces a plot having zero crossing points that mean this equation have roots but how to find roots accurate value is a question.

Comment: Try removing the braces in the definition of `V` and then do `rootU = NSolve[val == 0 && 0 <= U <= V[[2]], U][[All, 1, 2]]`.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your definitions a litte bit the way they make more sense to me. (e.g. what about the curios ß[[i]] and W[[i]] ?)

```
ncore = 1.4537; nclad = 1;
NA = Sqrt[ncore^2 - nclad^2];
\[Lambda] = 780*10^-9;
V[\[Rho]_] = 2*Pi*\[Rho]*NA/\[Lambda];
\[CapitalDelta] = (1/2)*(1 - (nclad/ncore)^2);
W = Sqrt[V[\[Rho]]^2 - U^2];
k = (2*Pi)/\[Lambda];
\[Beta] = Sqrt[(k*ncore)^2 - (U/\[Rho])^2];
i = 1;
\[Rho]list = {0.17*10^-6, 0.5*10^-6, 1*10^-6, 2*10^-6};


val[\[Rho]_, U_] = (((((1/2)*(BesselJ[0, U] - BesselJ[2, U]))/(U*
         BesselJ[1, 
          U])) + (((1/2)*(BesselK[0, W[[i]]] - 
           BesselK[2, W[[i]]]))/(W[[i]]*
         BesselK[1, 
          W[[i]]])))*((((1/2)*(BesselJ[0, U] - BesselJ[2, U]))/(U*
         BesselJ[1, 
          U])) + ((nclad^2*((1/2)*(BesselK[0, W[[i]]] - 
             BesselK[2, W[[i]]])))/(ncore^2*W[[i]]*
         BesselK[1, W[[i]]])))) - (((\[Beta][[i]])/(k*
        ncore))^2*(V[\[Rho]]/(U*W[[i]]))^4) /. 
    W[[i]] -> W /. \[Beta][[i]] -> \[Beta] // Simplify
```

I think you want 4 solutions of U for the 4 different `rho`

```
Plot[val[#, U], {U, 0, V[#]}] & /@ \[Rho]list
```

[image]

```
nsol = NSolve[val[#, U] == 0 && 0 <= U <= V[#], U] & /@ \[Rho]list

(*   {{}, 
     {{U -> 2.40483}, {U -> 4.06355}}, 
     {{U -> 2.40483}, {U -> 4.98827}, {U -> 5.52008}, {U -> 7.74422}}, 
     {{U -> 2.40483}, {U -> 5.10724}, {U -> 5.52008}, {U -> 8.36162}, {U -> 8.65373}, {U -> 11.5133}, {U -> 11.7915}, {U -> 14.5341}, {U -> 14.9309}, {U -> 16.768}}}
```

For first `rho` you get no solution, but second line for second solution, etc.